# State does not change back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Search input on my page. I want to change the color (from silver to green) whenever the search length is equal or greater than 1. This code is kind of broken. 
Now there are 2 problems:
1) It changes color after the length of search is equal to 2 or greater.

2) It does not revert back to it's original color (silver) when search field is empty after I clear whatever I input in my search field.

Please help!

```
export let change = 'bg-silver';

class Card extends Component {
  constructor({props, name, id, changeColor, change}) {
    super(props, name, id, changeColor, change);
    this.state = { 
        isToggleOn: true,
        name: name,
        id: id,
        changeColor: changeColor,

    };


    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
        }));
    }


  render() {
    const { name, id, changeColor, isToggleOn} = this.state;

    (changeColor.length > 1) ? change = 'bg-light-green'
    : change = change;

     return (

         isToggleOn ?
         <a style={{width: 200, height: 250}} className={'tc ' + change + ' dib br3 ma2 pa2 grow bw2 shadow-5'} onClick={this.handleClick}>
           <h2 className='f6 measure-narrow lh-copy'>{name}</h2>
        </a>

        : <div style={{width: 200, height: 250}} className='flex-wrap justify-center bg-light-green dib v-top ma2 br3 pa2 bw2 grow shadow-5' onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <p className='tc f6 measure-narrow lh-copy bg-silver br3 pa1 dib ma2 bw2 shawdow-5' >Hello, My name is <strong>{name}</strong><br/>
            How are you?</p>
        </div> 
    );
  }
}


export default Card;
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to change `changeColor`

Answer (score 2):

1) `changeColor.length > 1` - this means '2 or greater'. If you want '1 or greater' - use `> 0` or `>= 1`

2) You have set variable change value to 'bg-light-green' once. Using `change = change` will not do anything (assigning var to self).

Try:

```
change = (changeColor.length >= 1) ? 'bg-light-green' : 'bg-silver';
```

Comment: Can you paste the full code, please? Because it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change 2 things here:

1. `change = (changeColor.length >= 1) ? 'bg-light-green' : 'bg-silver';`
2. In your `handleClick ()` - change `setState` with this

> ```
> this.setState({
>     isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn 
> });
> ```

Comment: now when the search field is cleared, some of the searched items are in green and some in silver.

Comment: @TedKhi Can you share more code of where you are taking input and how you are passing the props?

Comment: Also please share the output if possible.